# Azure Service Fabric - connect to local service fabric cluster from outside the VM it's running on?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

We have a 5-node Azure Service Fabric Cluster as our main Production microservices hub.  Up until now, for testing purposes, we've just been pushing out separate versions of our applications (the production application with ".Test" appended to the name) to that production SFC.

We're looking for a better approach, namely a separate test Service Fabric Cluster.  But the issue comes down to costs.  The smallest SFC you can create in Azure is 3 nodes.  Further, you can't shutdown a SFC when it's not being used, which we would also need to do to save on costs.

So now I'm looking at just spinning up a plain Windows VM in Azure and installing the local Service Fabric Cluster app (which allows just one-node setup).  Is it possible to do this and be able to communicate with the cluster from outside the VM?

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to accomplish is setup a standalone cluster. The steps to do it is documented in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-for-windows-server) docs.

Yes, you can access the cluster from outside the VM, In simple terms enable access to the network and open the firewall ports.

Technically both deployments(Guide and DevCluster) are very similar, the main difference is that you have better control on the templates following the standalone guide, using the development setup you don't have much options and all the process is automated.

> PS:  I would highly recommend you have a UAT\Staging cluster with the
>   exact same specs as the production version, the approach you used
>   could be a good idea for staging environment. Having different
>   environments increase the risk of issues, mainly related to
>   configuration and concurrency.